# What is the definition of a physical thing?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-physics, definitions, physicalism

Physicalism is the view that only the physical exists. But that raises the question, what is the definition of a physical thing or object? Has any philosopher defined physicality? I would like some references for the definition of physical thing.

Comment: We could try to look at what we would put in the category _not physical_. What could go in there?

Comment: Or maybe we could explore what would happen if we defined "physical" as the closure of all things that interact with each other via one of the forces identified by physics. Of course, that definition should take into account that physics may yet discover new forces in nature. But maybe that's the best we can do as of today.

Comment: One might also ask how the physical relates to the material : whether all physical things are material things and all material things physical things. It's notable that while locuations such as 'a materialist theory of the mind' were once common, now the favoured locution is 'a physicalist theory of the mind'.  I assume the change of terminology is conceptual and not mere linguistic variation. If there is a conceptual change here, examination of it would throw light on the nature of the physical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the "definition" of physical is "what is studied by physics".  This leads to a major problem for phyiscalISTS to treat "physical" as an ontology, because physics is a science, and sciences are not static (what they study changes), and sciences always have a large unexplored and ill-defined boundary.  This leads to Hempel's Dilemma: any definition of what is or isn't physical will either allow the inclusion of things that physicalists want to exclude (spirit, abstractions) or will be false.  A recent book by Danial Stoljar on Physicalism explored a large suite of these proposed definitions, and one by one showed them to each be inadequate.  Here is a review:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R13R2OUNXMIN6H/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0415452627

Additionally, physicalism as originally conceived, presumed the "unity of sciences" principle of reduction of all other sciences to physics, plus the scientism assumption that all valid knowledge about our world is science knowledge. However, the recent abandonment of global reductionism as a failed project in the philosophy of science (see the section 5 of the SEP article on scientific reductionism, here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/), has undercut part of this presumption.  And the widespread concession that science CANNOT address the arts, philosophy, mathematics, etc., and a pluralist knowledge base is needed in both the sciences, and between science and non-science, has undercut the rest of it.  Most physicalist philosophers of mind today are non-reductive physicalists, and also are pluralists between science and non-science.  How a non-reductive physicalism can be an ontology at all, is generally not articulated.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world of physical objects, as manipulated by physicists and engineers, . a physical object is most conveniently defined as consisting of atoms. This means that a tire iron is a real physical object, but love or a magnetic field (both of which are still *real*) isn't.

Anyone who seriously considers a tire iron to be a subjective metaphysical construct is encouraged to try striking your toe with one. CAVEAT! Do not try this at home with anyone else's toe except your own, because the person to whom the toe is attached *might not* be a subjective metaphysical construct. You just never know...

Comment: The world of macro scale material objects appears to be emergent from physics.  PhysicalISM as an ontology therefore needs a very strong emergence principle.  Which is a subject that is still under construction.  There is no good emergence theory. This is a problem for physicalism, as the whole point of physicalism is to exclude causal consciousness, but emergence allows consciousness to be emergent, and causal.  Also spiritual entities could emerge from the material, or material from the spiritual.  Emergence plus pluralism seems to be needed for "physicalism" but enables all non phyiscalisms

Answer (score 0):

Matter = Physical. In the Wikipedia page it says that energy was added later so that physical meant matter or energy. This, to my reckoning, was unnecessary as matter is equivalent to energy (re mass-energy equivalene: E = mc², kind courtesy A. Einstein).

Scientific definitions:

1. Matter is defined as anything that has mass and occupies space.
2. Energy is the ability to do work.

So for x to be physical it must fulfill the following criteria:

1. x should have mass and volume (matter)

or

2. We should be able to do work with x (energy)

Comment: I think this is the perfect answer to the question. From this it is easy to determine also what is *not* physical.

Comment: Yes, this answer is how most physicalists think of physicalism.  As basically materialism under a new name.  There are problems with this view, and the non-newtonian "modern" physics as neither matter, energy or space are fundamental.  Examples -- space is no longer a given -- is this vague "space" which appears and grows -- matter?  It has no mass.  What is 'inflation", the process by which massive amounts of volume, mass and energy appear from nothing, a key feature of Big Bang models? And elementary particles "occupy" no space, they are just probabilistic wave functions.

Comment: @Dcleve, quantum wavefunctions have definite properties associated with them. They literally occupy all of space and have definite energies, momenta, and position. A portion of the wave-function only carries a portion of these properties. The inner-product of these wave functions determines the probability density function, which determines where the proportion of energy. Specific **interpretations** of what the wave and probability density functions mean (how they translate to english) yield different conclusions about reality. Most physicists trust the math over any specific interpretation.